# making a css menu with different start, end and breaks

Tags: css, menu, css-shapes

Hey guys was hoping you can help me out.

been at this for like more than an hour and its driving me crazy.

basically I am a big novice when it comes to CSS but am learning. at the moment I am trying to replicated a menu that looks like this:

[image: actual menu]

what I have so far looks something like this (i know the fonts different but not problem):
[image]

As you can see, ive got the background but I just CAN NOT figure out how make the start, end and the breaks (black line part) between each tab.

Also, basically the start, break, end I have as .jpg images. Not looking for html5 or css3 curves etc to do this. Just want to keep it simple :).

this is what I got so far. It would be great if you could could give me some tips on how I could make whats remaining and in case ive used a not-so-great approach, suggest an approach which would be better.

the html:

```
    <div id="header">

            <ul id="header-list">
                <li class="header-list-item">
                    <span class= "header-list-item-span" >Home</span>

                </li>

                <li class="header-list-item">
                  <span class= "header-list-item-span" >About Us</span>

                </li>
                <li class="header-list-item">
                   <span class= "header-list-item-span" >Services</span>

                </li>
            </ul>

    </div><!--END OF HEADER -->
```

the css:

```
#header-list{
  display: table;

 position: relative;
 left: -3em;

  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 0PX;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;

}

.header-list-item-span{
    background-image: url("img/menubody.jpg");
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em;
}

.header-list-item{
     display: table-cell;

 height: 4.2em;
  vertical-align:  bottom;

}
```

Comment: That black thing looks like a border. Go play with `border-left` and/or `border-right` and `margin` to push away the top and bottom.

Comment: So you need it as HTML5 or HTML4?

Comment: I did try it, but problem is border goes all the way down and all the up, however this has some gap between the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the ul in another div and add padding on the inside to the left and you can place your start image as the background. Then make the right image the background of the ul and add padding on the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div,li,ul,span { margin: 0;padding: 0;}

        body  { width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; }

        #header 
        {
            background: url(http://www.lucascobb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/1-plastic-navigation-bar-565x182.jpg) top center repeat;
            padding-top: 50px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #header .nav 
        {
            background: url(http://www.ultracomwireless.com/images/button_left.png) top left no-repeat;
            float: right;
            width: 413px;
            padding-left: 26px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        #header .nav .nav-wrapper 
        {
            background: url(http://www.ultracomwireless.com/images/button_right.png) top right no-repeat red;
            padding-right: 26px;
        }

        #header ul 
        {
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
        }
        #header ul li   
        {
            background: red;
            width: 120px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center; 
        }
        #header ul li span 
        {
             color: white; 
             padding: 8px 0px;
        }
        .clear { clear: both;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Home</span></li>
                    <li><span>About Us</span></li>
                    <li><span>Services</span></li>
                </ul>   
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the start image goes to the top left corner. I was able to vertically align the menu at the bottom because ul is display:table and li is display:table-cell

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll try to work out an example. :)

Comment: actually I solved it in a different way :).. added a new li at start and at end, with a different class, such that the class of the start and end have different backgrounds (i.e the background are the image of the start and the end) and the since you cant specify width, i added &nbsp in the <span> tags.. &nbsp basically adds a space that the browser shows and dosent omit. if you have another aproach, would love to hear it though since im learning :)

Comment: Well... you could just do that. haha ;D I don't like the wrapping required for this, but at the same time it's better html because when you remove all css you get the clean list of soon to be links and nothing else. I would stay away from &nbsp; as it's generally regarded as html clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

Wrap the `ul` in a `div`. Set the first jpg as a background image for that div, and add some `padding-left` so that the image can be visible.
Set the last jpg as a background image for the ul and add some `padding-right` so that the image can be visible too.

Also, in my opinion, you should simplify your HTML by taking more advantage of CSS selectors.

The header list can be selected as `div#header > ul`.
The items that you are selecting with the class `header-list-item` can be selected with `div#header > ul > li`.
I don't think the span is actually necessary, you could apply the styles directly to the `li` elements.